# Помогите с установкой virtualbox-qt

Tags: virtualbox

Хочу установить virtualbox-qt

> dpkg -i virtualbox-qt_7.0.12-dfsg-1_amd64.deb

выдает вот такую ошибку:

```
dpkg-deb: error: unexpected end of file in archive magic version number in virtualbox-qt_7.0.12-dfsg-1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error processing archive virtualbox-qt_7.0.12-dfsg-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 dpkg-deb --control subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-qt_7.0.12-dfsg-1_amd64.deb
```

что делать?

Comment: Скачать пакет заново. Он повреждён.

Comment: Проверь хэш-сумму md5sum virtualbox-qt_7.0.12-dfsg-1_amd64.deb